# If the solution is local/not global, but helped resolving the issue, does it still count for a good answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

Here is a link to [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37951694/).

After performing a research and trying various options, it turned out that reloading software (Visual Studio in my case) resolved the issue. However, if this is the case, the answer would be: "You got a runtime error? Not a problem, just reload your software!" I know it sounds ridiculous, and it normally should *not* resolve the problem on normal basis.

However, it *did* resolve my issue. So, if the solution was able to resolve an issue of one instance, but will not necessarily apply to everybody, will it still count as a legitimate answer? I always thought that answer should apply on global scale, that is why I am confused and asking here.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> I always thought that answer should apply on global scale

**Exactly**. While your question *certainly* isn't bad, it is *very unlikely* to help future readers, as you yourself noticed. Actually, restarting/reloading the IDE is usually the first option I recommend to my colleagues for *any* vague problem they mention.

In my opinion, the question should now be closed. There is even a specific close reason for these kind of problems:

> This question was caused by **a problem that can no longer be reproduced** ... While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: Then should I leave this question unanswered?

Comment: @VadzimSavenok You should vote/flag to close the question.

Comment: @VadzimSavenok or just delete it

Comment: It's worth noting that an *answer* can still be good despite what this post says about such a *question*.